# Setting up SSL at the server level on a VM

Tags: security, ssl, virtual-machines, azure

Forgive me if this is a trivial question, but I literally have zero experience in hardware administration.  I build websites/web apps, but usually use a third party like GoDaddy or Arvixe to facilitate all of the administration tasks.  Anyways, I have a VM on Azure that I need to set up SSL on.

1. Is SSL set up at the "site" level (in IIS), or the server level?
2. I need to create a self-signed certificate for development purposes-
   I do this in IIS.  Once I create my certificate, how do I apply it
   to the website in IIS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS, SSL certificates are bound at the site level.  In IIS7, click on the website you want to bind the cert to, on the right hand side you'll see "Bindings".

Open it, click "Add", select HTTPS.  Choose your certificate and enter a hostname (required if you're using a wildcard cert).

That should do it.

Comment: If this resolved your problem, please be sure to mark it as an answer.  Thanks!